# Experience upside down question mark when trying to insert hypen into the database

Tags: java, database, jsp, character-encoding

when tried to insert - or ' into the oracle database through java programming, the display turned out to be upside question mark ¿ in the place of '-'.

Example it look like

I¿ve joined a club of sorts. 
instead of  I've joined a club of sorts.

Input is through the text area and jsp coded as

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: Please specify the problem more exactly, giving input, expected and actual output and a code example. Also, you have to tell us which software you are using (JDBC? Oracle OCI or Thin driver?). I expect the problem to be a character encoding issue. So: Where does the input come from? Is it correctly encoded when it arrives in your Java application? Which encoding does the database use? Do you do any kind of encoding conversion? You really have to give more details when you ask us a question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your that all of your stuff is configured for using UTF-8 (or whatever charset you prefer):

- DB
- Java Sources (if the input comes from here, e.g. hard coded string)
- Resources (if the input comes from here, e.g. translation)
- Application Server (on Windows they start with a different encoding)
- HTTP Request (Content-Type)

I see this happening when devs who are not aware of character encoding issues work on systems with mixed infrastructure (e.g. app server on windows, db on linux).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem by copying text from an HTML email which came from a MS Word document, pasting into my JavaScript application's textarea field, and posting it to a Web API connected to an Oracle Database.

A quick string cleaning sufficed:

```
var tempDescription = myTextAreaContent;
if (tempDescription){
    tempDescription = tempDescription.replace('–', '-'); 
}
if (tempDescription){
    tempDescription = tempDescription.replace('’', '\''); 
}
```